# Google calendar php API gives file not found errors

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I don't know if this has been asked before, but I'm trying to set up a simple call to the google API to retrieve events from a calendar (eventually i want to do more than this, but this is a test project to try to get up and running)

I have set up the project in the google developer pages and got the keys and secret etc, and enabled the calendar API

I have a folder on localhost, inside which is a single php file and the folder containing the library.

What I am currently getting is file not found errors, such as

failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ... google-api\src\Google\Client.php on line 18

What I don't understand is that this is one file in the library (Client.php) referencing another file (Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php) in the same library, so do I need to go through the entire library, editing all of the paths, or am i missing something? (or doing something really wrong?)

Many thanks,

John

Comment: try reading though this http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/ its not Google calendar api so you will need to change the service to a calendar service.  But it explains a bit of how the oauth2 flow works and where you need to have the directory for the client lib.

Comment: Thanks, that would appear to have fixed the problem! can't believe that in all the online tutorials and documentation, I had missed the fact you were supposed to move the files to the root ! What I now have is a folder that contains an index.php file and the Google folder copied from the library download. The file not found errors have now gone, although I now get an error "Undefined index: logout in ... \index.php on line 14". Many thanks for your help.

Comment: everyone has that problem.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [installation documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation#what-to-do), you need to ensure that the /src folder is in your include_path. Alternatively, as you've found, you can just copy the /src/Google directory into the root of your application.